# HTML/JQuery Drop bown box changing text on another field

Tags: jquery, html

So here's a screenshot: http://prntscr.com/f3g1hi
Basically, I'm wanting "Email Address:" to change to "10 digit phone number:" when the Format: (drop down box) is set to SMS, but have "Email Address:" when the drop down box is set to email. My knowledge on JQuery is very limited at the moment.

Here's my code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Format:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select class="form-control">
        <option>SMS</option>
        <option>Email</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Email Address:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please include screenshot, not link to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a custom `show-on` attribute along with `values` to tether them to.

```js
$(".show-tether").change(function () {
  $("[show-on='"+$(this).val()+"']").show().siblings().hide();
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Format:</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <select class="form-control show-tether">
      <option value="sms">SMS</option>
      <option value="email">Email</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div show-on="email">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Email Address:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div show-on="sms">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone number:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="SMS" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing the bootstrap call. Also I'd remove input type="email" for phone #. There are custom validators for phone number, but they are not built into bootstrap by default. (HTML's input type="tel" is only supported in safari). Otherwise good solution.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late reply!